# How to allow betatesters with dynamic IPs to bypass the IP redirection in htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, .htpasswd

Ok, the question might sound a little complicated but I'm having an issue and I hope I can get some advice from you guys.

So I'm building a website. Currently all visitors are redirected with my .htaccess to my Coming Soon page, except from certain IP addresses. This all works fine.

Now a few of my betatesters have a dynamic IP address. So I can't give them access to the site using the method I've used until now. I could password protect the website using .htpasswd, but then I'd loose the redirection to my coming soon page, no?

Anyone who has a suggestion to give betatesters with a dynamic IP access to my website, while other visitors are redirected to my coming soon page?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you have a 'coming soon' page for most visitors, and put the site to actually test under a sub-directory which is password protected?  You can then give the testers the subdirectory site to go to, and everyone else will see the 'coming soon' page

Comment: I've thought about that, but I mostly used absolute URLs in my files, so I'd have to change all of them to the new directories and change them back afterwards and I have a LOT of files.. But I'll consider it since I don't really see any other way, thanks for your reply :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use query string and cookie.
In your `.htaccess` add these lines before your "coming Soon" redirect:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} test=betatesters1 [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} test=betatesters1
RewriteRule ^ - [CO=test:betatesters1:yourdomain.com,L]
```

The first access without cookie:

```
http://yourdomain.com/?test=betatesters1
```

I use `test=betatesters1` but you can use what you want not too easy to guess

Comment: Thanks, this looks like a perfect solution! Just one question, is this a safe method? Can people who don't have the 'password' (test=betatesters1) find a way to access the site? Or is this fairly safe?

Comment: For me it is a very safe solution. The only problem is with the original cookie. A better method than query string would to provide a link to a page reserved to beta testers which would add the cookie (
for example in PHP) and you can even protect this page with password

Comment: Ok thanks, then I will use this method :) What do you mean exactly with "The only problem is with the original cookie"?

Comment: And in addition you can change the cookie each time you want to restrict access to testers. Or use several cookies (for various parts of the site)

Comment: The only problem is with the original cookie because you talk to the testers, and then they suspect that this is the mechanism used

Comment: I understand, but I only have a few testers and I completely trust them so there's not really a problem with the cookies. Thanks for your help!

Comment: And for example as if your site includes external sources (publicity). They could see the first QUERY_STRING...

Answer (score 1):

### Use a subdomain

One option that I have seen frequently used is to have a test site, such as `staging.yourdomain.com` which is `.htpasswd` protected. Your testers use that site leaving the main `www.yourdomain.com` still able to redirect the public to your coming soon page.

This can also be expanded on, if you have some testers with static IP addresses, the `.htaccess` can be adjusted to bypass the password requirements for those ip addresses.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Since I don't really have that option atm I will use Croises' method for now, but I will certainly think about using your method in the future.